# DBD::Oracle::st execute failed: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string in clob

Tags: sql, oracle

Another problem with my SQL. 
I am inserting a clob data as json string in to my table:

```
Name              Null     Type         
----------------- -------- ------------ 
ID                NOT NULL NUMBER       
SAMPLENAME        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) 
STUDY_ID                   NUMBER       
STOCK_ID          NOT NULL NUMBER       
BARCODE                    VARCHAR2(25) 
WELL                       VARCHAR2(3)  
DATA                       CLOB         
DATE_ADDED                 DATE         
DATA_TYPE         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)  
IS_CURRENT        NOT NULL NUMBER       

DBD::Oracle::st execute failed: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 65 in
 'insert into results values(:p1,:p2,:p3,:p4,:p5,:p6,:p7,:<*>p8,:p9,:p10)')
```

And running them through a command -line gives me :

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.
```

This is the insert statement:

```
insert into results values(1060,'teresta1232',3149,354600,1381992393,'A01','{'data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj','data1':''fjfaskfj'}','2014-08-13T00:00:10','F',1);
```

Comment: In the insert statement it looks like you're missing a whole lot of escaping. see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a74ac/7 for an example of how to escape a string with quotes in, and how to specify a date in that format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is your value for the date column DATE_ADDED

```
2014-08-13T00:00:10
```

You didn't specify any format for this date conversion. So implicitly oracle is try to convert into date using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`

You have to explicitly specify the date format like one below for consistent results.

`TO_DATE('2014-08-13T00:00:10','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

Comment: but the problem lies with the 8th value and not in the 9th.  I shall check whether that helps.

Comment: My bad. It did complain about my 8th value but changing the date resolved it. Thanks